# How to create a shortcut for user's build system in Sublime Text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

I've just created a build system named `XeLaTeX` by creating a file named `XeLaTeX.sublime-build` in the `User` directory of Sublime Text, whose content is:

```
{
    "cmd": ["xelatex.exe","-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","$file_base_name"]
}
```

What should I do, if I want to bind my <kbd>F1</kbd> key to this specific build system?

Note: <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>, the default build system should not be influenced. That is to say, I could use <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> to use the default one, and the key <kbd>F1</kbd>, the new system, is also available at the same time.

---

Maybe there is another way to achieve this. Add the following text to `Default(Windows).sublime-keymap` will execute the command:

```
{"keys": ["f1"], "command": "exec", "args": {"cmd": ["xelatex.exe","-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","$file_base_name"]}},
```

However, `$file_base_name` is not defined here. Is there any method to pass current file (base_)name to `exec`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I nailed it by myself.

AFAIK, there is no such a way to pass current file name through key binding, and it's not possible to use key binding to specify a certain build system. Thus, writing a Python script is of necessity.

There are only three steps.

**1.** Save the following content to `/Data/Package/User/compile_with_xelatex.py`:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CompileWithXelatexCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
   def run(self, edit):
      self.view.window().run_command('exec', {'cmd': ["xelatex.exe","-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode", self.view.file_name()[:-4]]})
```

**2.** Add a line to `/Data/Packages/User/Default(<your-plat>).sublime-keymap`

```
{"keys": ["f1"], "command": "compile_with_xelatex"},
```

**3.** Open your LaTeX source file with Sublime Text, and then press <kbd>F1</kbd> to compile it with XeLaTeX.

Indeed, it's a little tricky, but it works like a charm for me.

Comment: I used a modification of this script to get Sublime Text to run with Black (the formatter). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Build systems work by either selecting them specifically in the `Tools -> Build System` menu, or by using a selector to match a specific syntax. If you want to use a selector, add the following line to your `XeLaTeX.sublime-build` file (make sure to add a comma `,` after the first line, the file needs to be valid JSON):

```json
"selector": "text.tex.latex"
```

The `build` command is already bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd>, but if you also want it bound to <kbd>F1</kbd>, open `Preferences -> Key Bindings-User` and add the following line if you already have custom key bindings:

```json
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "build" }
```

If the file is empty, just add opening and closing square brackets `[ ]` at the beginning and end of the file, respectively, as it also needs to be valid JSON.

Now, whenever you open a LaTeX file, you *should* be able to hit <kbd>F1</kbd> to build it. If for some reason it doesn't work (if, for example, you have other build systems for LaTeX installed by plugins like `LaTeXTools`), then just select `Tools -> Build Systems -> XeLaTeX`, and everything should work properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm afraid this is not I want. I have two build systems that are designed for LaTeX, say `LaTeXmk` and `XeLaTeX`. Since `LaTeXmk` would compile the soure file three, or even more, times, wasting a lot of time, a method that could specify build system manually is needed.

Comment: Same here. I have two build for "source.java", one to compile the current file, one to compile all files in the current directory. Because there's two, "Tools > Build" is unclickable. My workaround is to use "Alt > T > U > J > Enter" to compile the current file, and "... J > J ..." to compile all.

Answer (score 1):

Your example will work, if you give parameter "$file_basename" not "$file_base_name".