# How to make Sublime Text select a custom Build System automatically?

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext3

There are some documentation out there that explains how to write a custom build system for compiling using `C++11`. Rigth now I'm able to compile `C++11` code, but I have to select the build system from the `Tools->Build System` menu.

Before that (when I was workin only with Python and C++98) I use to have just selected `Tools->Build System->Automatic` and I was able to compile(run in case of Python) both just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

I want that Sublime Text to use automatically my `C++11` custom Build System instead the default `C++`. There are some way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

Just take the `C++11` build system file and name it as: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/C++/C++.sublime-build`

That way it will compile with that Build System automatically (if Tools->Build System->Automatic is selected) each time C++ syntax is detected.

For those that want to have the option to select either C++11 or C++98, or any other you can follow the link posted by JeremyCraig:  [How to create a shortcut for user's build system in Sublime Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403119/how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-users-build-system-in-sublime-text).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I would make this a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. But is this something like what you want?

[How to create a shortcut for user's build system in Sublime Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403119/how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-users-build-system-in-sublime-text)

EDIT:
(thank you Roger Fan)

which says (in case the link dies):

AFAIK, there is no such a way to pass current file name through key binding, and it's not possible to use key binding to specify a certain build system. Thus, writing a Python script is of necessity.

There are only three steps.

**1**. Save the following content to `/Data/Package/User/compile_with_xelatex.py`:

```
    import sublime, sublime_plugin

    class CompileWithXelatexCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
      def run(self, edit):
        self.view.window().run_command('exec', {'cmd': ["xelatex.exe","-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode", self.view.file_name()[:-4]]})
```

**2**. Add a line to `/Data/Packages/User/Default(<your-plat>).sublime-keymap`

`{"keys": ["f1"], "command": "compile_with_xelatex"},`

**3**. Open your LaTeX source file with Sublime Text, and then press F1 to compile it with XeLaTeX.

Indeed, it's a little tricky, but it works like a charm for me.

Comment: That could do the work for those that want have options. I just want to pres Ctrl+B and compile with C++11. However, is a goo link, thanks.